# WiFi and Battery not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, battery

I got the Epik Teqnio 12.5" laptop, but `lspci` doesn't show the WiFi card, and there is no battery icon. I checked the BIOS and there is no option there. What can I do?

Comment: What operating system? You may be out of luck. This is a very low-end laptop, and this sounds like a BIOS problem, and a newer BIOS may not be available. Is there a manufacturer's web site where you can check?

Comment: It came with windows, but I’m trying to get it to work with Ubuntu. I’ll check the driver in Windows and put in my question as soon as I can.

Comment: It's the BIOS you need to check to see if there's a newer version available.

Comment: The latest daily build kernel recognizes the battery, but still no WiFi. I think that shows that it isn't a BIOS problem.

Comment: I also keep on getting `Request firmware failed with error 0xffffffe` when in the terminal, which other similar problems are for WiFi cards. I also noticed that when running `lsusb`, one has no description next to it, which leads me to believe that it is the wifi card.

Comment: You may need to install `linux-firmware`. See if the card shows up in `lspci`. Lets see `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: The question is very unclear. There is no information about the wireless device or an Ubuntu version.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's a "Bay Trail" so... SDIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. All I needed to do was install the latest daily kernel build for Ubuntu, and install drivers(from my other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945422/ifconfig-wlan0-up-error))