# ifconfig wlan0 up error

Tags: wireless, ifconfig

Whenever I run `ifconfig wlan0 up` I get:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

my `lshw -C network` shows:

```
  *-network:1 DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: [REMOVED]
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

`dimes` shows the following error:

```
Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin failed with error -2
```

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`? And is it really `wlan0`? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: `lshw` shows the logical name as `wlan0` and I was running it as root

Comment: What does `rfkill  list` show?

Comment: Soft block and hard block are no.

Comment: What's the output of `ip l`? Does `ip l set wlan0 up` work?

Comment: `ip l set wlan0 up` gives `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

Comment: enabling the driver for it `r8723bs` still won't fix the issue.

Comment: Please run: `dmesg | grep rtl` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a driver issue. Installing the drivers from https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs fixed my WiFi.